# How to make the Developer Express popup menus semitransparent like in Firefox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, devexpress, contextmenu

I am using DevExpress Build 47.
Is there a way to make the context(aka popup) menus semi transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no Opacity property for DevExpress' PopupMenu control. You may experiment with PaintMenuBar event and use e.Graphics but I think it's easier to propose DevExpress a new feature.